# If-Else tree using Case Function or VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

This code works, however, my if/else statement tree is long and repetitive with only a few changes being the values the variables are set to for each case.

I have read `Select Case` is good when testing multiple conditions, for my case `wsName` and `rate_value`.

How could I either use the `Select Case` method or a VLOOKUP table?

For reference, `wsName` and `rate_value` are defined before these lines are called.

```vb
If wsName = "Test-3" Then
   If rate_value < 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 95
   ElseIf rate_value = 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 98
       sweep_value = 49.8
       sweep_value_max = 50.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 100 Then
       snapdownvol = 110
       sweep_value = 99.8
       sweep_value_max = 100.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 200 Then
       snapdownvol = 110
       sweep_value = 199.4
       sweep_value_max = 200.4
   ElseIf rate_value > 200 Then
       MsgBox "Rate Value for " & sysnum & " is greater than 200 kHz. Rate Min and Max will be 0."
   End If
ElseIf wsName = "Test-6" Then
   If rate_value < 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 98
   ElseIf rate_value = 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 98
       sweep_value = 49.8
       sweep_value_max = 50.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 100 Then
       snapdownvol = 125
       sweep_value = 99.8
       sweep_value_max = 100.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 200 Then
       snapdownvol = 125
       sweep_value = 199.4
       sweep_value_max = 200.4
   ElseIf rate_value > 200 Then
       MsgBox "Rate Value for " & sysnum & " is greater than 200 kHz. Rate Min and Max will be 0."
   End If
ElseIf wsName = "Test-8" Then
   If rate_value < 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 98
   ElseIf rate_value = 50 Then
       snapdownvol = 98
       sweep_value = 49.8
       sweep_value_max = 50.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 100 Then
       snapdownvol = 125
       sweep_value = 99.8
       sweep_value_max = 100.2
   ElseIf rate_value = 200 Then
       snapdownvol = 125
       sweep_value = 199.4
       sweep_value_max = 200.4
   ElseIf rate_value > 200 Then
       MsgBox "Rate Value for " & sysnum & " is greater than 200 kHz. Rate Min and Max will be 0."
   End If
End If
```

Comment: You should consider a dictionary of dictionaries. with the inner dictionary having an array paired with the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a lot of repetition, I would go for the Case Select:

```
Select Case rate_value
    Case Is < 50
        Select Case wsName
            Case "Test-3"
                snapdownvol = 95
            Case "Test-6", "Test-8"
                snapdownvol = 98
        End Select
    Case Is = 50
        snapdownvol = 98
        sweep_value = 49.8
        sweep_value_max = 50.2
    Case Is = 100
        Select Case wsName
            Case "Test-3"
                snapdownvol = 110
            Case "Test-6", "Test-8"
                snapdownvol = 125
        End Select
        sweep_value = 99.8
        sweep_value_max = 100.2
    Case Is = 200
        snapdownvol = 110
        sweep_value = 199.4
        sweep_value_max = 200.4
    Case Is > 200
        MsgBox "Rate Value for " & sysnum & " is greater than 200 kHz. Rate Min and Max will be 0."
End Select
```